# Android ViewPager multiple item visibility

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, scrollview

I am trying to list cards just like in the picture. When scrolling the next item should come front by growing and and the current item should get smaller. 
When i try to set pageMargin to the viewpager the next and previous items are come to the correct position but the other items become visible too. 
Is there any library that provides this?

[image: cards should be listed like this]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could extend ViewPager class, and then override method onMeasure.

The second way is to set negative padding on viewPager:

```
viewPager.setPageMargin(-30);
viewPager.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
viewPager.setFadingEdgeLength(20);
```

Comment: The central item won't Zoom in with this code. That's the biggest issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/clkasd/CarouselViewProject) project as a guide to implement Carousel effect you have mentioned.